# Multibranch pipeline - Jenkins - How to execute one branch at a time?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

Merry xmas guys,

I have got a very basic question that I didn't find out there:

How to build branches one at a time?

I actually have two branches to be built set in my multi-branch pipeline Jenkins process.  However, when I hit run, if no changes, both are built at the same time which is a problem due to the unit tests that are using the same port.

This is why I would need to run one branch at a time.

Is there any way in which I can do this?

Comment: I think it is wiser to solve the problem with your unittests, not hack around that.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot limit branches being built with the Multibranch Pipeline. But you can limit that only one step/stage is being run at a time, even across branches, with a [lock](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin)

```
stage("Unit Test") {
  lock("unit_test_lock") {

    //Unit tests here

  } // resource is unlocked.
}
```

If two branches A and B build concurrently, A will first acquire the lock, while B will wait for the lock to be released. So the branches will never execute this locked stage concurrently.

Comment: FYI this does not come with the default Jenkins install. You need add the plugin "Lockable Resources" to Jenkins.

Comment: Note that This will mean you're still consuming an executor with build B until A is finished.